# Ruby on Rails: How to change all my 'Show edit destroy' buttons using bootstrap button group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Show</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Destroy</button>
</div>
```

So I want to use bootstrap to change my 'show/edit/destroy' buttons in all my indexes using this code. But I have no idea how to do it. Help?

Edit: I have bootstrap set up and working

Comment: For starters, do you have bootstrap in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @DanRubio Sorry I wasn't more clear. Yes I have bootstrap set up and working.

Comment: Ok, so going down the check list did you do everything specified in the Getting Started section? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails
It's not clear to me what problem your having. Are you getting an error? Are the stylesheets not found. What specific part about doing the bootstrap buttons are you having a problem with?

Comment: Bootstrap is working 100%. I'm just a complete noob and I don't know where to put this code to make the edit/destroy/show buttons change for all my indexes

Comment: If Bootstrap is indeed working properly, you need to add that html code into your view file where you want it. So if you have .erb.html files in `app/views/example_view.erb.html` you add it there in erb styling. The display should change to bootstrap style automatically provided you installed bootstrap correctly.

Comment: So bootstrap is working, you just want to change the button color or something?

Comment: These are the hardest buttons to button.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you what to do something like this

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <%= link_to "show", show_path, class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <%= link_to "edit", edit_path, class: "btn btn-info"%>
  <%= link_to "destroy", delete_path, class: "btn btn-danger", data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete%>
</div>
```

Of course `show_path`, `edit_path` and `delete_path` are there as examples, check the specific path => `rake routes`